# How variable sizes are related to processors arhitecture?

Tags: memory, microprocessor

I often come into the situation where I am not sure how big is my variable, for instance: integer, short, long?

I know that I can find size of variable with sizeof(); function in C.

But now I'm in situation where I'm trying to parse some data from file and I have that file structure, when I realize that all that is written for an 8bit microcontroller, I am not sure how can I know how much data INT represents in that documentation? Is it 8 bit - 1B ?
How size of variables depends on processor arhitecture? If I am correct max variable size in an 8bit processor is 1B, so char - int and all other variables are 1B maximum size?

Comment: Short answer: they're not.

Comment: Yet another good reason for using [stdint.h](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdint.h).

Comment: @RogerRowland Sadly `stdint.h` was introduced with C99 and many of the types it defines are optional, i.e. an implementation may also dispense with them. So for maximum portability, especially if no great C compiler is available, you are stuck with some preprocessing tricks to define your own int type as a typedef for a predefined type with the right bit width. Moreover, see the [criticism](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdint.h#Criticisms_and_caveats) in the same article you linked to.

Comment: @RogerRowland In particular see section **7.18.1.1 Exact-width integer types** of C99 draft standard N1256 (par.3): `These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides integer types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that have a two’s complement representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names.` I agree that on most PC these conditions are met, but I don't know about all MCUs, especially the conditions about padding. YMMV

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Yes, agreed. Not perfect, but better than nothing and at least an attempt to move in a better direction ...

Comment: @RogerRowland Yep! Definitely!

Comment: So, just to be clear: 1. The file of data you are trying to parse already exists? 2. You have a specification of the file structure, defined using C, or C data types? If any of these are **not** true, then please clarify. 3. The file contains *binary*, and not text (i.e. it does not look correct when you look at the file with a text editor)? If that is *not* true then you have a different problem. Do you know which compiler and compiler flags (maybe in a make fie?) were used to create the file? Knowing that may be enough to correctly parse the data from a binary file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if your 8-bit processor only supports data handling at 8 bits, the compiler will handle all the necessary stuff for a 16-bit addition and passing on data, so the size in bits of int, short or others are purely based on your compilers settings.

Normally you will find this information somewhere in the compiler manual.

To get out of this trouble it is a good practice not to use the compiler defined types directly. You might want to include stdint.h (if available) which provides clearly named datatypes such as uint8_t which is an unsigned integer with 8 bits.

If you cannot use this, create your own version of it and create a header with something along those lines (or get a complete stdint.h and adapt it to your compiler):

`typedef unsigned char uint8_t`

where you of course have to check your compiler manual to get the right compiler types.

This [wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdint.h) gives a nice explanation of stdint.h.

There are some problems though, as especially for embedded devices not all data types are supported by all compilers. 64-bit data types are often missing, so there are two possible outcomes: either your program won't compile anymore (I think that is the good case) or someone has `typedef`ed the 64-bit data type to a smaller one and your program might return unexpected results because of that.

In my opinion if a data type is not supported it should lead to a compilation error, so the programmer is actually aware of the problem before hitting it in the system.

As an example on where to find that information for a compiler:

The IAR Embedded Workbench comes with a bunch of documentation, for this kind of information, you have to look in the Development Guide, and there under the Reference Information you will find the Data representation. Under that point you will find all necessary details to handle data correctly. Alignment, Size and Range are all given there.

```
Data type              Size      Range             Alignment
bool                   8 bits    0 to 1            1
char                   8 bits    0 to 255          1
...
signed long long       64 bits  -2^63 to 2^63-1    8
unsigned long long     64 bits   0 to 2^64-1       8
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at your C compiler documentation. It should spell out the answers you need.

An 8-bit compiler may have "int" be 8-bits, 16-bits or something else. In some cases the number of bits in a default "int" may be selectable via a compiler command line switch or environment variable.

Comment: If the compiler would try to adhere to the C standard, it wouldn't make ints 8 bits. The C standard requires the an int type is at least 16 bits.

Comment: A C compiler that has an 8-bit int is seriously broken. The C89 standard does not say the minimum number of bits or the representation explicitly IIRC but specifies a range that requires at least 16 bits.